# problem sharing printer via samba in Ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: printing, password, samba, username

I have cannon ImageRunner 1133 I want to share it through samba with cups server installed on Ubuntu server 12.04

it works all fine I installed samba and cups server  ubuntu and windows clients can successfully print via samba but I want every user when they click the share printer they should be prompted for username and password for this I have edited smb.conf file and set guest ok = no under printers it works for Ubuntu clients but when windows 7 clients click on the share printer it does not prompt for username and password